# d3.ease fade image in

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am calling the following function and passing it the location of an image:

```
function show_image(source) {
        var img = d3.select("#right-section").append("img").attr("src",source)
        img.transition().duration(5000).easeLinear;
    }
```

Here is the function that uses some JQuery to empty the relevant HTML div object (right-section) and then show the image:

```
function Con1aaRight(div) {
    $("#right-section").empty();  
    show_image("images/netflix.jpg");    
}
```

The problem is the image is showing but not fading in like I would like it to (with d3.ease in the show_image function). I probably should be using JQuery but I would like to incorporate d3. Similar transition/animation ideas welcome. I am building a scrolling webpage tutorial on a data science topic with text on the left and images on the right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is understanding what is a D3 transition and how it works.

A D3 transition, as the name implies, transitions from one state, or value, to another state.

That being said, you can, for example, transition...

- A position: from `x = 10` to `x = 60`.
- A color: from `green` to `blue`.
- A font size: from `10px` to `18px`.
- An opacity: from `0.2` to `0.9`.
- A stroke width: from `1px` to `5px`.

... and several other attributes/styles.

However, you **cannot** transition this:

- non-existence ➔ existence

As Bostock, creator of D3, once said (emphasis mine):

> When modifying the DOM, use selections for any changes that cannot be interpolated; only use transitions for animation. For example, it is impossible to interpolate the creation of an element: **it either exists or it doesn’t**. ([source](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/))

**Solution**: transition the *opacity* of the image:

```js
var body = d3.select("body");

show_image("http://www.defenders.org/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/tiger-dirk-freder-isp.jpg")

function show_image(source) {
  var img = body.append("img").attr("src", source).style("opacity", 0)
  img.transition().duration(5000).ease(d3.easeLinear).style("opacity", 1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: get rid of that jQuery code. You **don't** need jQuery when using D3. Mixing jQuery and D3 is not only unnecessary but also, in some cases, it will make things silently break.